# Shortcut key is not working in eclipse RCP java project

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, keyboard-shortcuts

I have eclipse RCP java project, in which i have enabled shortcut keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for save and other activities. it was working fine until i have imported my project in 64 bit Eclipse indigo. Most of the keys are working but these two not. I have checked <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> is associated with defaultHandler.

Now it is throwing following Exception:

```
ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2015-01-21 15:07:08.646
!MESSAGE A handler conflict occurred.  This may disable some commands.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2015-01-21 15:07:08.646
!MESSAGE Conflict for 'org.eclipse.ui.file.save':
HandlerActivation(commandId=org.eclipse.ui.file.save,
    handler=org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SaveHandler@4e65ad52,
    expression=,sourcePriority=0)
```

**Update:**

```
public class KBShortcutsHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

        if (event.getCommand().getId().equals("org.eclipse.ui.file.save")) {
                        new XyzHandler(XConstants.SAVE_EDITOR_ID)
                .run();
        }
    }

}
```

in plugin.xml

```xml
     <command
            defaultHandler="KBShortcutsHandler"
            id="org.eclipse.ui.file.save"
            name="save">
      </command>
```

and simply write code to "Add Action" it was working fine but not now.

Comment: Show us how you are setting up your handlers.

Comment: @greg-449 I have updated question please look in to this. I want to figure out what is the problem that making it disable for 64 bit eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse already has a definition of the `org.eclipse.ui.file.save` command so you should not be trying to define it yourself. Instead use the `org.eclipse.ui.handlers` extension point to define a handler to be used when your code is active.

The following is an example of how the Debug plugin handles the 'delete' command:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
  <handler
        class="org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.views.launch.TerminateAndRemoveHandler"
        commandId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.delete">
     <activeWhen>
        <iterate
              ifEmpty="false"
              operator="and">
           <adapt
                 type="org.eclipse.debug.core.model.ITerminate">
           </adapt>
        </iterate>
     </activeWhen>
  </handler>
</extension>
```

I notice your constants `XConstants.SAVE_EDITOR_ID` - if you are trying to save in an editor there should not be any need to do anything if it is based on EditorPart.

Comment: I just noticed that save is now working with Ctrl+Shift+S and ctrl +H still not working. what is it? (Shift + S = Caps S). is there any problem with handlers/

Answer (score 0):

- This "org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.7.1.v20120104-1859.jar" workBench
  jar must contain the SaveHandler class which is present inside
  org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers package.
  Below line must removed from plugin.xml

This works for me.